# copy excel sheet data to another sheet or file using VBA while running a function on data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy entire data of a worksheet to another sheet or file but I want to check each cell and reverse it if its data type is text. So far I got the function to find the data type and the one to reverse the text.
Here are the functions:

```
Function reverseText(text)
    reverseText = StrReverse(text)
End Function
```

And:

```
Function CellType(Rng)
Application.Volatile
Set Rng = Rng.Range("A1")
Select Case True
    Case IsEmpty(Rng)
        CellType = "Blank"
    Case WorksheetFunction.IsText(Rng)
        CellType = "Text"
    Case WorksheetFunction.IsLogical(Rng)
        CellType = "Logical"
    Case WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Rng)
        CellType = "Error"
    Case IsDate(Rng)
        CellType = "Date"
    Case InStr(1, Rng.text, ":") <> 0
        CellType = "Time"
    Case IsNumeric(Rng)
        CellType = "Value"
End Select
End Function
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` to check each populated cell for text and reverse it...

```
Public Sub testReverse()
    Dim cell

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If CellType(cell) = "Text" Then
            cell.Value = reverseText(cell.Value)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Function reverseText(text) As String
    reverseText = StrReverse(text)
End Function

Function CellType(Rng) As String
    Application.Volatile
    Select Case True
        Case IsEmpty(Rng)
            CellType = "Blank"
        Case WorksheetFunction.IsText(Rng)
            CellType = "Text"
        Case WorksheetFunction.IsLogical(Rng)
            CellType = "Logical"
        Case WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Rng)
            CellType = "Error"
        Case IsDate(Rng)
            CellType = "Date"
        Case InStr(1, Rng.text, ":") <> 0
            CellType = "Time"
        Case IsNumeric(Rng)
            CellType = "Value"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @WhiteHat ! Worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your case, like this -

```
Case WorksheetFunction.IsText(Rng)
    CellType = "Text"
    Rng = StrReverse(Rng.Value)
```

If you want to call your function, then you'd do something like this -

```
Case WorksheetFunction.IsText(Rng)
        CellType = "Text"
        reverseText (Rng.Value)
        Rng = reverseText
```

I'd give your function a type if you did it this way. Something like -

```
Function reverseText(text As String) As String
    reverseText = StrReverse(text)
End Function
```